# Merge tags software and software-rec?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

There are now questions tagged [software](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) and [software-rec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-rec). All [software](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) questions look like they're software recommendations and should be tagged `software-rec` for compatibility with [Super User](https://superuser.com/). I'm not sure whether [software](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) should be a synonym of [software-rec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) or if it has some independent legitimate use here (in which case the questions should be retagged).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the [software](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) posts do seem to be recommendations, except for [List installed packages in Fedora](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/list-installed-packages-in-fedora). I dropped the tag from that one and merged [software](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) → [software-rec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-rec):

> updating post history, 8 rows affected
>   updating posts, 7 rows affected
>   updating PostTags associations, 7 rows affected
>   removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
>   updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
>   merge of [software-rec] and [software] complete!

I'm not sure if it should be a synonym or not, so I didn't make one for now

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine a question that should be tagged [software](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) and not [software-rec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-rec). It makes sense for E&R, but not here. Since this is a Unix & Linux site, all questions relate somewhat to software - it's a given.

Comment: I just retagged http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3322/what-makes-osx-programs-not-runnable-on-linux then wondered if `software` hadn't been a legitimate tag after all.

Comment: @Gilles That does seem like a rare legitimate usage, but the tag itself isn't particularly helpful; nobody's going to search for all [software] posts